# Microtype's tracking feature works with some fonts, not others

Tags: fonts, small-caps, microtype, libertine, letterspacing

In the code below, tracking works with the [`libertine`](http://ctan.org/pkg/libertine) font, but not with the [`Alegreya`](http://ctan.org/pkg/alegreya) font. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 100]{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine} % <- tracking works with small caps 
%\usepackage{Alegreya} % <- tracking does not work with small caps 
\begin{document}
\textls{ABCD} \textsc{abcd} \textls{\textit{ABCD \textsc{abcd}}}
\end{document}
```

libertine:

[image]

Alegreya:

[image]

Comment: Is it on purpose that you have the first `\textsc` outside of `\textls`?  Because this is the one where tracking does not work.

Comment: @nickie It does work with `libertine`. Tracking is supposed to be automatic for small caps, so using `textls` isn't supposed to be necessary there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new version of [`Alegreya`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/alegreya), in which the definition of `\scshape` has been changed to be more properly handled, tracking will work out of the box without the need for `\DeclareMicrotypeSet` as in [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240049/9077).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 100]{microtype}
\usepackage{Alegreya} % <- tracking now works with small caps 
\begin{document}
\textls{ABCD} \textsc{abcd} \textls{\textit{ABCD \textsc{abcd}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have the latest Alegreya package (2015-10-22) and I still need the \DeclareMicrotypeSet in order to get the smallcaps tracking.

Comment: @Ludenticus My version is (2015-10-04), so for some reason the newest version must've broken what the previous version fixed. I'll let the maintainer know.

Comment: @Ludenticus Neither the package maintainer nor I are able to replicate your issue.

Comment: My fault. I didn't check directly my system's version, as I thought it was updated, provided that Arch Linux is usually «bleeding edge». After manually installed the newest package, I confirm it works. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 10):

with Alegreya small caps are a family and not a shape and so the default settings of microtype don't affect them. You must activate tracking yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 500]{microtype}


\usepackage{Alegreya} % <- tracking does not work with small caps
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{alegreyasc}   
{ font = */AlegreyaSC-TLF/*/*/* }

\begin{document}
\textit{ABCD} \textsc{abcd} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `otfinfo` command to find information about a particular OpenType or TrueType font.  In particular, use the `-f` flag to find about the features that it supports.

It seems that, in contrast to Libertine (which is OpenType), the roman version of the Alegreya font (which is TrueType) does not feature small caps.  Therefore, the small caps you see are not natively supported by the font.

I am not an expert in fonts and I cannot tell you why this makes a difference for the tracking mechanism of `microtype`.  If you add the `\textls`, it will work for Alegreya too.

Compare:

```
$ otfinfo -f /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_R.otf
aalt    Access All Alternates
c2sc    Small Capitals From Capitals
case    Case-Sensitive Forms
ccmp    Glyph Composition/Decomposition
cpsp    Capital Spacing
dlig    Discretionary Ligatures
fina    Terminal Forms
frac    Fractions
hlig    Historical Ligatures
kern    Kerning
lfbd    Left Bounds
liga    Standard Ligatures
lnum    Lining Figures
mark    Mark Positioning
mkmk    Mark to Mark Positioning
nalt    Alternate Annotation Forms
onum    Oldstyle Figures
pnum    Proportional Figures
rtbd    Right Bounds
salt    Stylistic Alternates
sinf    Scientific Inferiors
smcp    Small Capitals
ss01    Stylistic Set 1
ss02    Stylistic Set 2
ss03    Stylistic Set 3
ss04    Stylistic Set 4
ss05    Stylistic Set 5
ss06    Stylistic Set 6
sups    Superscript
tnum    Tabular Figures
zero    Slashed Zero
```

with:

```
$ otfinfo -f /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/huerta/alegreya/Alegreya-Regular.ttf
cpsp    Capital Spacing
dnom    Denominators
frac    Fractions
liga    Standard Ligatures
lnum    Lining Figures
numr    Numerators
onum    Oldstyle Figures
pnum    Proportional Figures
sinf    Scientific Inferiors
sups    Superscript
tnum    Tabular Figures
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't exactly what I'm asking. I'm using Type 1 fonts in my MWE, not the `.otf`/`.ttf` fonts. As my MWE shows, both the `libertine` and the `Alegreya` Type 1 fonts have small caps. Also, the Alegreya `.ttf` fonts do have small caps as well, but they're put in a separate font, so you won't find them in the `Alegreya-Regular` font that you've looked in here.

Comment: @Sverre OK, sorry I can't help more.  You're obviously more of an expert in fonts than I am.  I'm leaving the answer here, in case it's helpful for anybody who can figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, though `:)`