# Set tracking for small caps fonts with microtype

Tags: fonts, microtype, letterspacing

This is the exact same question as [Microtype's tracking feature works with some fonts, not others](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240027/microtypes-tracking-feature-works-with-some-fonts-not-others). Only this time I'm trying to accomplish the same with a different font.

Bob Tennent has kindly converted the [`IM Fell English`](http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/imfellEnglish) fonts into LaTeX fonts after I suggested it to him just a few days ago. But I can't figure out how to set tracking for its small caps font.

The accepted [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240049/9077) by @UlrikeFischer for how to do that with the [`Alegreya`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/alegreya) fonts is clearly tailored to that specific font family, and I don't know how to modify it for `IM Fell English`.

I'd appreciate if someone could show us how to do that, ideally with some explanations of the code so that I wouldn't have to ask again for the next font family I come across.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 500]{microtype}
%\usepackage{Alegreya}
%   \DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{alegreyasc}{font = */AlegreyaSC-TLF/*/*/*}
\usepackage{imfellEnglish}
    \DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{imfellenglishsc}{font = */IM_FELL_English_SC-TLF/*/*/*}
\begin{document}
\textsc{Hello world!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct family name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 250]{microtype}
\usepackage{imfellEnglish}

\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{imfellenglishsc}{font = */IMFELLEnglishSC-TLF/*/*/*}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Hello world!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The family name can be deduced from the directory structure of the package distribution:

```
LY1IMFELLEnglish-TLF.fd
LY1IMFELLEnglishSC-TLF.fd
OT1IMFELLEnglish-TLF.fd
OT1IMFELLEnglishSC-TLF.fd
T1IMFELLEnglish-TLF.fd
T1IMFELLEnglishSC-TLF.fd
TS1IMFELLEnglish-TLF.fd
TS1IMFELLEnglishSC-TLF.fd
imfellEnglish.sty
```

Comment: I see. I took the file name from the `tfm` folder in `texmf-dist\fonts`.

Comment: Follow-up: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271033/set-tracking-for-small-caps-selected-by-scshape