# Set tracking for small caps selected by \scshape

Tags: fonts, sectioning, microtype, small-caps, letterspacing

If a font family doesn't have a bold font, it makes sense to me to use small caps instead. But when I redefine `\bfseries` to mean `\scshape`, there's no tracking in those small caps. How can I set that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 250]{microtype}
\usepackage{imfellEnglish}
    \DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{imfellenglishsc}{font = */IMFELLEnglishSC-TLF/*/*/*}
    \renewcommand*{\bfseries}{\scshape}
\begin{document}
\section{The first section}
\textsc{Abcde}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Under which system/format should this MWE be run? LuaLaTeX? I have MacTeX2015 with all the latest updates installed (including the imfellEnglish package), and I get a `\xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D` error when trying to run your code under LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Mico With `latex` (`pdflatex`).

Comment: @Mico If you have the latest updates that is fixed

Comment: @JosephWright - Hmmm, something must be really messed up with my MacTeX installation: I can't run Sverre's code successfully under either pdflatex or lualatex. I even deleted everything under `/usr/local/texlive/2015`, reinstalled MacTeX from scratch, and ran `tlmgr` to run a complete update. Unfortunately, no difference, i.e., I still can't compile the MWE. (For completeness, let me mention that I upgraded to MacOSX 10.11 "El Capitan" on Sept. 30.)

Comment: @Mico I think you belong to a growing population who are having difficulties running LaTeX under El Capitan. I think there are questions here on TeX.sX on that, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new fix to [`IM Fell English`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/imfellenglish) (see [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271043/9077)), it's longer necessary to use `\DeclareMicrotypeSet`, and tracking is automatically applied to `\scshape`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 250]{microtype}
\usepackage{imfellEnglish}
    \renewcommand*{\bfseries}{\scshape}
\begin{document}
\section{The first section}
\textsc{A ff fi} A ff fi
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `imfellEnglish` package is making a fundamental error: in order to use a different set of fonts for small caps it redefines `\scshape` as a family changing command; the problem should instead be solved at the `.fd` file level.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 250]{microtype}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

% save the meaning of \scshape
\LetLtxMacro{\latexscshape}{\scshape}

\usepackage{imfellEnglish}

% provide good form of the family declaration
\makeatletter
\expandafter\ifx\csname IMFELLEnglish@scale\endcsname\relax
    \let\IMFELLEnglish@@scale\@empty
\else
    \edef\IMFELLEnglish@@scale{s*[\csname IMFELLEnglish@scale\endcsname]}%
\fi
\makeatother

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{IMFELLEnglish-TLF}{}

\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{IMFELLEnglish-TLF}{m}{n}{
      <-> \IMFELLEnglish@@scale IM_FELL_English_Roman-tlf-ot1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{IMFELLEnglish-TLF}{m}{it}{
      <-> \IMFELLEnglish@@scale IM_FELL_English_Italic-tlf-ot1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{IMFELLEnglish-TLF}{m}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * IMFELLEnglish-TLF/m/it
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{IMFELLEnglish-TLF}{m}{sc}{
      <-> \IMFELLEnglish@@scale IM_FELL_English_SC-tlf-ot1
}{}

% restore the meaning of \scshape
\LetLtxMacro{\scshape}{\latexscshape}

% microtype settings
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{imfellenglishsc}{
  family = IMFELLEnglish-TLF,
  shape = sc,
}

% no bold face
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\scshape}

\begin{document}

{\Large\scshape Hello world!}

\textsc{Hello world!}

\section{The first section fi ff}

Is this tracked as well? fi ff

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Update (October 6, 2015)

The package `imfellEnglish` has been updated and now the simpler code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 250]{microtype}
\usepackage{imfellEnglish}

\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{imfellenglishsc}{
  family = IMFELLEnglish-TLF,
  shape = sc,
}

\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\scshape}

\begin{document}

{\Large\scshape Hello world!}

\textsc{Hello world!}

\section{The first section fi ff}

Is this tracked as well? fi ff

\end{document}
```

will return the same output as above.

Comment: I don't know why, but this code will apply letterspacing to regular text as well, not just to small caps.

Comment: @Sverre Now it should be OK. Please, make Bob Tennent aware of the issue.

Comment: @Sverre As I was certain of, Bob has fixed the issue.

Comment: Right, we've been in touch about it. Thanks for finding the problem. The same issue also applies to other fonts of his, such as `Alegreya`, which he has also fixed now. I don't understand why `imfellEnglish` doesn't show up on `ctan.org`, though.

Comment: Also, could you explain why it's necessary to use these `\SetTracking` commands, and why you've changed `font = */IMFELLEnglishSC-TLF/*/*/*` to `font = */IMFELLEnglish-TLF/*/*/*`. Why isn't it sufficient to just add the sizes?

Comment: @Sverre That evades me and I'm inclined to say it's a feature of `microtype`. The meaning of “feature” is what you prefer. `;-)` The change in the name is for complying with the font family name.

Comment: I've always interpreted "feature" to mean "[dead moths](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/H96566k.jpg)".

Comment: @Sverre @egreg: It's not a moth. You should say `\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{imfellenglishsc}{
  family = IMFELLEnglish-TLF,
  shape = sc}`, and then you can delete the `\SetTracking` commands. I think you misunderstood the `font` key and/or the meaning of the asterisk, which may well be the fault of `microtype`'s documentation.

Comment: @Robert Actually it's not necessary to use `\DeclareMicrotypeSet` at all as long as the `\scshape` definition is properly handled in the font - see [my new answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271763/9077).